# Values after FFT

Tags: ios, objective-c, fft, accelerate-framework

I'm trying to create an audio visualizer.

I'm using the fast Fourier transform to find the frequencies.

```
memset(_window, 0, sizeof(float)*_windowSize);
memset(_A.imagp, 0, nOver2 * sizeof(float));

vDSP_hann_window(_window, _windowSize, vDSP_HANN_NORM);

for (int i=0; i < _windowSize; i++) {
    if (player && ioData) {
        _inPutBuffer[i] = ((SInt16*) ioData->mBuffers[0].mData)[i];
    }
}

vDSP_vmul(_inPutBuffer, 1, _window, 1, _transferBuffer, 1, _windowSize);

vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX*)_transferBuffer, 2, &(_A), 1, nOver2);

vDSP_fft_zrip(_fftSetup, &_A, stride, log2n, FFT_FORWARD);

vDSP_vsmul(_A.realp, 1, &_scale, _A.realp, 1, nOver2);
vDSP_vsmul(_A.imagp, 1, &_scale, _A.imagp, 1, nOver2);

_A.imagp[0] = 0.0f;

vDSP_zvmags(&_A, 1, _obtainedReal, 1, nOver2);

float frequencyArray[n];

for (int i=1; i <=kIndicatorsCount; i++ ) {
    float res = 0;
    for (int j=0; j <=32; j++) {
        res += _obtainedReal[i*32+j];
    }
    res = res / 32;
    OutputBuff[i] = res;
}
```

But the output is very different values, for example, in one case the output values ​​can be from 0 to 1, and the other from 0 to 5.0E +6.

Is it possible to bring the output values ​​to a certain range (Eg 0 to 1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magnitude output of the FFT is usually visualized in [decibels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) for this very reason.  Decibels allow very small components to still be seen when large components are present.  The conversion is simple.  Since `vDSP_zvmags` gives the squared magnitude, you can convert to dB with:

```
dbval = 10 * log10(mag2val);
```

or see `vDSP_vdbcon`.

This could be normalized between 0 and 1 by dividing by the maximum value of your dB values, but you probably don't want to change this reference point dynamically since it would cause visualization of a constant magnitude to jump around. It would probably be better to just figure out what ranges are typical and normalize to that fixed value.

Comment: Floating point samples in CoreAudio are supposed to normalize 1.0 to the input's full-scale value.

Comment: I'm quite new to audio stuff, and I'm having a little trouble understanding how to get from an FFT to decibels. Could you by any chance explain these steps a little, or point towards a good explanation? =)

Answer (score 1):

The problem should be vDSP_zvmags(&_A, 1, _obtainedReal, 1, nOver2);

As per Apple doc :
vDSP_zvmags Calculates the squared magnitudes of complex vector A.

I mean the magnitude is per Pitagora Theorem and you should use
vDSP_vpythg
(Vector Pythagoras; single precision.)

After that you can use decibel conversion vDSP_vdbcon with flag
 __vDSP_F to
Power (0) or amplitude (1) flag

Hope this help